# How to close sub menu items using jquery this

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, css-transitions

I have created a menu with three levels and would like any open sub menu's to close when you click on a new sub menu header. I have managed to get it working for the first sub menu's but not for second sub menu's, when I click on the second sub menu it closes the because I have tried to reuse the same class for both levels is there a way round this? Also since I have removed the class in the function it has stopped closing sub menu's when you click on their header, is there a way to accomplish this as well:

Html:

```
 <nav id="main-nav" role="navigation">
        <div class="block">
            <h2 class="block-title">Main menu</h2>
            <ul>
                <li class="is-active">
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                </li><!--
             --><li>
                    <a class="toggle-sub-nav" href="#">Link ></a>
                      <ul class="sub-nav">
                          <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                </li><!--
             --><li>
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                </li><!--
             --><li>
                    <a class="toggle-sub-nav" href="#">Link ></a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                          <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                          <li> <a class="toggle-sub-nav" href="#">Sub Link ></a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                          <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                      </ul></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                </li><!--
             --><li>
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
           </div>
</nav>
```

CSS for sub menus:

```
.sub-nav { 

     height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
    -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
    -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
    -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
    transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
    overflow:hidden;

  }


  .sub-nav-open {

    height: auto;
    max-height: 500px;

  }

.sub-nav li { background-color: #666; }
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".toggle-sub-nav").click(function() {
        $('.sub-nav').removeClass('sub-nav-open');
            $(this).next(".sub-nav").toggleClass('sub-nav-open');
            return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to avoid the closing of the first level.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $(".toggle-sub-nav").click(function () {
        $('.sub-nav').not($(this).closest('.sub-nav')).removeClass('sub-nav-open');
        $(this).next(".sub-nav").toggleClass('sub-nav-open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/CnEy8/

Comment: Thank you works a treat. Do you know how I can get the sub menu's to close when clicking their headers again?

Comment: Hi I have noticed one issue on Android Google chrome. When you open a sub menu and then close it again the next time you open it the sub menu links are missing have you come across this?

Comment: Irvin's second Fiddle does the job but bear in mind that andSelf was deprecated in 1.8 and subsequently removed. You'll want to use addBack.